# Obtener día de la semana en numero del dia actual

Tags: c#

Esto me da como reultado: "Viernes" pero necesito el numero, osea 6, empezando desde el domingo.

```html
string dia = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la propiedad [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2) del objeto `DateTime` que es en este es es `Now`; Esta propiedad regresará un enum de tipo `DayOfWeek`, simplemente lo casteas a `int` y obtendrás el numero de dia de la semana.

```
int diaSemana = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa el enumerador `System.DayOfWeek` que se expone en la propiedad `DayOfWeek` de la clase `System.DateTime`. El enum puedes "castearlo" a int y así obtienes el número.

```
foreach (var weekDay in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
            Console.WriteLine($"{weekDay} = {(int)weekDay}");   

Output:
-------
Sunday = 0
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday = 4
Friday = 5
Saturday = 6
```

En tu caso sería:

```
var dia = (int) DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Te dejo un link a los docs para más info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza lo siguiente:

```
string dia = Convert.ToString((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
```